# ¿Cómo introducir un Combobox dentro de una grid con varias columnas?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Estoy usando Ext.js y tengo un botón que defino así:

```
tbar: ['', '->',{
      text: 'Add date',
      scope: this,
      handler: this.addNew
    }],
```

Cada vez que hago click sobre él, me agrega una *grid* para cada columna. Colocaré fotografía para explicarme mejor en esta parte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi función dentro del botón, es la siguiente:

```
addNew: function () {
  var me = this;
  var grid = me.down('[name=globalValuesGrid]');
  var rec = {
                'globalvalue': '', 'uuidglobalvalue': '', 'valuetoassign': '', 'uuidvaluetoassign': ''
            };
  grid.getStore().insert(0,rec);
  me.cellEditing.startEditByPosition({
                row: 0,
                column: 0
            });
},
```

Pero a la hora de iniciar y probar, me dice lo siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing is not a constructor

Cabe resaltar que el `CellEditing` lo tengo dentro del `InitComponent`. Y éste es su código:

```
me.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
        clicksToEdit: 2
    });
```

¿Por qué recibo ese error?¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Funciona si quitas el `new` en `me.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({ ... })`?

Comment: De hecho, si, pero lo agregue en mi linea dentro de la grid y ya funciona perfecto. gracias! :)

Comment: Genial. Agrégalo como respuesta y acéptala (incluyendo el código clave que ha cambiado) para que pueda servir de referencia a otros usuarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución.**

Coloque mi línea de código que tenía el problema:

> me.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
>           clicksToEdit: 2
>       });

Dentro de mi `grid`y quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
items:[{
          xtype: 'grid',
          name: 'globalValuesGrid',
          plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {clicksToEdit: 1})], ...
```

También tuve que modificar algunas cosas dentro de mi función para agregar, la que se emplea en el botón.

```
addNew: function () {
  var me = this;
  var grid = me.down('[name=globalValuesGrid]');
  var rec = {
                'globalvalue': '', 'uuidglobalvalue': '', 'valuetoassign': '', 'uuidvaluetoassign': ''
            };
  grid.getStore().insert(0,rec);
},
```